# model.update performance in the model

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, gurobi, linear-optimization

I have a question about performance of the model.update in the gurobipy library.

Let's say I have a list of objects which I want to add as a variable to the model, also I want to add a constraint to each of this object, to do that I have a for loop in which I do the following

```
for object in list:
    some_parameter=object.parameter
    model.addVar(name=object.name)
    model.update()
    model.addConstr(
                model.getVarByName(object_name) >= some_parameter
            )
```

Of course my loop is more complex, this is just a simple example. I am getting this message in the log:

INFO     : Warning: excessive time spent in model updates.
INFO     : Consider calling update less frequently.

My question is now: is the right solution to this is to make two loops instead of one like this:

```
for object in list:
    model.addVar(name=object.name)
```

then call

```
    model.update()
```

and then run the loop with adding the constraints?

```
for object in list:
    some_parameter=object.parameter
    model.addConstr(
                model.getVarByName(object_name) >= some_parameter
            )
```

Which one is the usual way, or maybe I should do it completely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's the usual way to add all the variables first. Note that the `model.addVar()` method already returns the variable which can directly be used without calling `model.update()`. Therefore, you don't need the `model.getVarByName()` method to obtain access to the variable. Instead, you can do something like this:

```py
# add the variables
y = {}
for ob in object_list:
    y[ob.name] = model.addVar(name=ob.name)

# add the constraints
for ob in object_list:
    model.addConstr(y[ob.name] >= ob.parameter)

model.update()
model.optimize()
```

After the model has been solved, you can then easily access the variable values through the `.X` attribute, i.e. `y[ob.name].X` gives you the variable value where `ob` is an element of your `object_list`.

Comment: Is calling getvarbyname also a costly operation? Is saving the vars in the dictionary indeed a performance booster?

Comment: `optimize` includes an `update` call, so it's not necessary to call it manually. And yes, `getVarByName` is certainly more expensive than accessing a readily-available data structure which should always be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, you should consider using `addVars()` ([documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_model_addvars.html)) and pass your list directly. This will return a [tupledict](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/py_tupledict.html#pythonclass:tupledict) that you can then use to formulate your constraints and the objective.

This approach is typically the fastest and most pythonic as you are not using any manual for-loops while still providing easy access to your variables.

Finally, calling `update()` is not necessary in most cases, especially not right before calling `optimize()` because there is an implicit `update()` call happening anyway.